# Render a list of tags using template HTML element

Tags: javascript, html

I discovered today the `template` tag and I really like it.

```
<div class="items">
    <template id="item-template">
        <div class="item">
            <div class="text">
                <p>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing
                    elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut
                    labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam
                    voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo
                    dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren,
                    no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor.
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="source">
                Lorem ipsum, pag 12
            </div>
            <div class="tags">
                <a href="#">Tag 1</a>
                <a href="#">Tag 2</a>
                <a href="#">Tag 3</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </template>
</div>
```

I used the template like this and it is working:

```
var quotes = [
    {
        text: "asdasd asdasd asdasdasd asdasd1",
        source: "source 111",
        tags: ["123", "18767"]
    },
    {
        text: "asdasd asdasd asdasdasd asdasd2222",
        source: "source 222",
        tags: ["22223"]
    },
    {
        text: "asdasd asdasd asdasdasd asdasd333",
        source: "source 333",
        tags: ["33323", "3338767"]
    },
];


function render_quote(text, source, tags) {
    var item_template = document.getElementById("item-template").content;

    var clone = document.importNode(item_template, true);
    clone.querySelector("div.text").textContent = text;
    clone.querySelector("div.source").textContent = source;
    clone.querySelector("div.tags").textContent = tags;

    return clone;
}

if ('content' in document.createElement('template')) {
    var items_container = document.querySelector("div.items");

    quotes.forEach(quote => {
        items_container.appendChild(render_quote(quote.text, quote.source, quote.tags));
    })

} else {
    console.log("template feature missing.");
}
```

The problem is I don't know how to render the list of tags. I want to keep them as links. And the tags number is not the same all the time. Can you give me a hint?

Comment: Why don't you use `v-for`?
`<div class="tags"><a href="#" v-for="(tag, i) in tags" :key="i">Tag {{i + 1}}</a></div>`

Comment: @scar-2018 Why are you suggesting a Vue feature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could replace `clone.querySelector("div.tags").textContent = tags;` by

```js
clone.querySelector("div.tags").innerHTML = tags.reduce((html, tag) => html += `<a href="#">${tag}</a> `, '');
```

Note that I use `innerHTML` where you use `textContent`

```js
var quotes = [
    {
        text: "asdasd asdasd asdasdasd asdasd1",
        source: "source 111",
        tags: ["123", "18767"]
    },
    {
        text: "asdasd asdasd asdasdasd asdasd2222",
        source: "source 222",
        tags: ["22223"]
    },
    {
        text: "asdasd asdasd asdasdasd asdasd333",
        source: "source 333",
        tags: ["33323", "3338767"]
    },
];


function render_quote(text, source, tags) {
    var item_template = document.getElementById("item-template").content;

    var clone = document.importNode(item_template, true);
    clone.querySelector("div.text").textContent = text;
    clone.querySelector("div.source").textContent = source;
    clone.querySelector("div.tags").innerHTML = tags.reduce((html, tag) => html += `<a href="#">${tag}</a> `, '');

    return clone;
}

if ('content' in document.createElement('template')) {
    var items_container = document.querySelector("div.items");

    quotes.forEach(quote => {
        items_container.appendChild(render_quote(quote.text, quote.source, quote.tags));
    })

} else {
    console.log("template feature missing.");
}
```

```html
<div class="items">
  <template id="item-template">
    <div class="item">
      <div class="text">
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing
          elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut
          labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam
          voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo
          dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren,
          no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor.
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="source">
        Lorem ipsum, pag 12
      </div>
      <div class="tags">
        <a href="#">Tag 1</a>
        <a href="#">Tag 2</a>
        <a href="#">Tag 3</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </template>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

just do it in this way!

````js
function render_quote(text, source, tags) {
    var item_template = document.getElementById("item-template").content;

    var clone = document.importNode(item_template, true);
    clone.querySelector("div.text").textContent = text;
    clone.querySelector("div.source").textContent = source;
    const tagsContainer = clone.querySelector("div.tags")
    tags.forEach(tag => {
        const tagElement = document.createElement('a');
        tagtagElementiv.textContent = tag;
        tagElement.href = "#"
        tagsContainer.appendChild(tagElement);
    })

    return clone;
}```;
````

Comment: What's dirty about this? It'd be great for you to add a paragraph explaining what the problem was and how this solution solves it. That will make your answer friendly to anyone who comes across the same problem.